why mapstruct always instantiate target class on nested bean mapping?
I am using MapStruct, and I have some nested bean mapping. My problem is that I don't want any empty objects instantiated in my target class.
Is there a way to tell MapStruct not to instantiate any target members before doing the mapping? Or maybe to set the property to null?
Here is my example:
Source class:
public class Source {
    private String v;
    protected List<SourceAType> agrp;
    // some getter and setter
}

public class SourceAType {
    private String a;
    // some getter and setter
}

Target class:
public class Target {

    private String v;
    private TargetANt targetANt;
    // some getter and setter
}

public class TargetA {
    private String A20;    
// some getter and setter
}

public class TargetANt {
    protected TargetA[] array;
    // some getter and setter
}

Mapper Definition:
@Mapper
public abstract class SourceToTargetMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "v", target = "v")
    @Mapping(source = "agrp", target = "targetANt.array")
    public abstract Target mapSourceToTarget(Source input);
}

It produce this mapping method:
 protected TargetANt sourceToTargetANt(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        TargetANt targetANt = new TargetANt(); // Here are my problem
        if ( source.getAgrp() != null ) {
            targetANt.setArray( sourceATypeListToTargetAArray( source.getAgrp() ) );
        }
        return targetANt;
    }

As you can see in the mapstruct compilated method, i will always get an empty TargetANt.
Of course, I can use @ObjectFactory to only generate the TargetAnt if source.getAgrp() is empty. However, I’m talking about a lot of mappings, and creating this for each one would be overkill. Maintaining the code would be difficult.
I've tried NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS. "It does what it should, but the target class will already be created."

TargetANt is always instantiated because it the wrapper of the nullable array, not the reference to the mapped array itself. Mapstruct does not "prune" classes that has only null references inside. If you have a number of classes that are in a similar condition, you may implement a reusable @ObjectFactory so to centralize the custom policy and keep it simpler to maintain.
